# Set Default template for category page

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, theme

New to Magento.

Can any one guide me how to define a default layout for category pages.

Tried local.xml in my theme folder but not working.

Here is my xml file :-

```
<!-- Default handle, loaded on most pages -->
<default>

    <reference name="head">

        <!-- Remove Magento's default assets -->
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/print.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/styles-ie.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/styles.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/widgets.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/ie6.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>varien/menu.js</name>
        </action>

        <!-- Add our assets -->
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/font-awesome.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/jquery-ui.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>dist/css/style.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/ddSlick.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/parsjewellers.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery-ui.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/ddSlick_jquery.dropdown.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>dist/js/script.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/my_site.js</name>
        </action>

        <!-- Add additioanl child blocks -->
        <block type="core/template" name="boilerplate.head.meta" template="boilerplate/page/html/head/meta.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="boilerplate.head.ie8" template="boilerplate/page/html/head/ie8.phtml"/>

    </reference>

    <reference name="header">
        <block type="directory/currency" name="custom_currency_selector" template="currency/currency.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="right">
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo" />
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
        <remove name="right.poll" />
        <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="currency" />
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
        <remove name="tags_popular" />
        <remove name="left.newsletter" />
    </reference>

</default>

<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>


<print>

    <reference name="head">

        <!-- Add our assets -->
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/script-ck.js</name>
        </action>

    </reference>

</print>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the file name is `local.xml`, not `loacal.xml`

and here's an example how to change layout of category page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Layout update above will change regular category layout template and layout template of category with layered navigation to 2columns-right.phtml.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Sorry for the typo.
Yes it was overwritten by catalog_category_layered handle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using layered navigation? It is possible that it's be overwritten by the `catalog_category_layered` layout handle.

Comment: Try changing your layout handle to catalog_category_layered

Answer (score 0):

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

That looks right to me.  Two things though:

In your question you spelled it "loacal.xml" which isn't right.  If that's your actual filename, it should be `local.xml`.

Alternatively:  if your cache is turned on it needs refreshed to update the changes.  I would suggest turning caching off entirely until you're done working on your shop, it'll save you a lot of "why isn't this working?!"